# how do i show a popup on page load in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to show a popup the moment the login screen loads. how do i do this in ionic? my current code in controllers.js is:

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
template: 'Do you have your one-time mobile password from the website?',
title: 'Credentials Confirmation',
scope: $scope,
buttons: [
  { text: 'Yes' },
  {
    text: 'No',
    type: 'button-positive',
    onTap: function(e) {
      myPopup.close();
      } 
    }
  }
]
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code & write the popup code in it. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached view.

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function(event, data){
 //popup code here
});
```

Reference URL : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Let me know if you face any issue

**Updated:**

```
 var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                          template: 'Do you have your one-time mobile password from the website?',
                                       title: 'Credentials Confirmation',
                                       scope: $scope,
                                       buttons: [
                                                 { text: 'Yes' },
                                                 {
                                                 text: 'No',
                                                 type: 'button-positive',
                                                 onTap: function(e) {
                                                   myPopup.close();
                                                 }
                                                 }
                                                 ]
           });
```

Comment: have you added "$ionicPopup" in dependencies?

Comment: yes, code is: .controller('opaySignUp15Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$ionicPopup','userFactoryReg', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, ionicPopup, userFactoryReg) {

Comment: Please check, you have not applied "if" condition only else is there.

Comment: You have added `ionicPopup` not `$ionicPopup`

Comment: @SydnieS was it helpful?